# Bucket names in S3 not being created with spaces or special characters anymore

Tags: android, amazon-s3

I use android to upload files to S3 in my app. When I was using the sdk version 2.6.+, my buckets were created with spaces and special characters without any problem. But after I upgraded my versions of S3 and SQS in gradle to 2.7.+, my buckets now have the characters of URL. The spaces now are %20, for example.
I really need my buckets stay with spaces and special characters, but from android side I've found anything that could help me, and I don't know much about S3.

Can someone help me please? Only to remember, the only thing I've done was upgrade the version of sdk and I can't downgrade it.

Comment: Which region are you using? Traditionally, `us-east-1` permitted non-DNS compliant names, while other regions required DNS-compliant names so that bucket names could be used in URLs (eg `mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com`).

Comment: I'm using us-east-1 region @JohnRotenstein

Answer (score 0):

Are you using 2.7.4 or 2.7.5? If so, this fix in 2.7.6 may help. [Fixed the regression introduced in 2.7.4 to support transfer objects with name containing special characters.](https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-android/releases/tag/release_v2.7.6)

Comment: Didn't work. I've tried with 2.7.6, 2.8.2 and 2.8.3 and none of that worked with special characters :(
In my transferUtility.upload function I can see that the address is going with the special characters without any problem, but in S3 the problem still happens